# WinForms: Show new form in the same window

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm an experienced MVC developer making my first attempt at an internal WinForms production app for the company I work for.

When my app first loads it loads a LoginForm (which inherits from BaseForm to set things like window size, NotifyIcon properties, etc). On successful login, I want to retain the same window, but replace the content with a new screen. This seems pretty basic but even after searching for how to do this, none of it works like I would expect it to.

I've tried code like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 W1 = new Window1();
    W1.Show();
    this.Close();    
}
```

But of course, that opens a new window and closes the current one, which isn't what I want. I want to retain the same parent window and just replace the content.

I have two questions (they're sort of related):

1) How do I simply replace parent window content with a new Form instead of opening it in a new window? Right now my forms are in separate WinForms controls (LoginForm and ChatForm). Do I need to architect my project differently in order to accomplish this?

2) The ChatForm contains a SplitContainer with buttons on the left (see screenshot below). On clicking each button, the content of the right hand pane should change. Would these be best represented by UserControls (one for the ChatQueue, one for a ChatWindow, passing in parameters to let it know which person we're chatting with)?

Just trying to get my head around basic WinForms project architecture and navigation between different content screens.

[image]

Comment: My suggestion would be to clear all the controls (or those u want to be gone) and then add others on the same form.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the first "Window"'s Controls on a Panel with `Dock = DockStyle.Fill` instead of directly on the Form. And the second "Window"'s Controls on another similarly `Dock`ed Panel. Both Panels being on the Form. Then `panel1.SendToBack();`. (Or  `panel2.BringToFront();`.)

Or you can:

```
Controls.Remove(panel1);
Controls.Add(panel2);
```

if you'd rather do that.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, you have to architect the project in a different way.

Think of a Form as one parent form. All other forms(Login, Chat) need to be designed as user controls. Then you have to place all the controls in the parent form and have to manage the sequence of these controls programmatically i.e. Login should precede Chat etc. Then introduce  a class similar to NavigationController, which'll be responsible for managing the sequence of the controls i.e. hide login and show chat etc. The class may maintain a stack internally to manage the transitions.

2) Yes, you are right. The same concept of using UserControls applies here!

And it is true that MVC developers find very tough time while working with WinForms. But the good news is that you can accomplish a similar design in WinForms by manually implementing the theoretical concepts of MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you create a login user control and chat user control.

To compare to web, a window is like a page... You can't switch pages without refreshing so if you want to keep the cool ajax look and feel you create a one page app and stick different controls in it.

As for architecture, placing all controls on the window level or using layout controls (panels) to create a logical seperation is not advised.

Building a good hirerchy of user controls is the standard architecture for winforms apps.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

To get this effect, I would lay out the right-hand side using a `TabControl` and simply switch the tab page based on the button clicked.

There are ways to hide the tabs too, if you want, which would simulate something like swapping `Panel` controls, but without the ugly `Controls.Add()` calls.